# Teamcity: Stop build running when other build is running?

Tags: teamcity

I have two builds running in teamcity. One deploys the db, the other makes an app and then runs against the db.

So my problem is, i dont want the db build to start if the second is running.
So i need the database build not to trigger/wait until the other is finished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [snapshot dependency](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Snapshot+Dependencies) on build(B1) that you would like to wait on the other build(B2)
Assuming B1 needs to start only after B2 is complete

Comment: Thank, this is what ive done. Even there is no code dependency between the two build.

Comment: Um actually not what i need as the snapshot dependency is building the other build every time.

Comment: The snapshot dependency builds the other one only if there are source changes, which is what must be expected, read the first bulleted point @ 'http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Dependent+Build#DependentBuild-SnapshotDependency'

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to create one build configuration with two build steps. Then set limit of running build configuration to one and you are done.

Comment: can you elaborate?